# Could not load file or assembly error in child application for handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

In IIS i have a parent application(Default Website) and it has child applications. I am writing the http handler in my parent application and this http handler will be the gateway for all child applications as well so when any child application URL hits it will go through by http handler in parent app.
After deplyment when i try to open the child applications it gives me the error of

> Could not load file or assembly 'Intelligize.QC.Web' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

here is my web.config file in parent app

```
  <httpHandlers>
   <add verb="*" path="*" type="Intelligize.QC.Web.AuthorizationHandler, Intelligize.QC.Web" validate="true" />
 </httpHandlers>
```

Please help me in this solution. I have already waste too much time on that

Comment: did you find a solution? or you just follow to copy all bin folder?

Answer (score 2):

Child application is inheriting Parent applications web.config file.

Write this on your parent application web.config file to avoid inheritance of web.config file in child application:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.web>
        ...
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: But i want that handler to work on my child applications as well. As i said that handler will be the gateway for parent and child apps

Comment: Are you getting my point: I want 1 httphandler for parent and all child apps

Answer (score 1):

For more info on such error enable FusionLog. [Here](http://www.programering.com/a/MjNzADMwATg.html) you can read how. In log files you can see your assembly load information and fix it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that this handler is working as gateway for your child applications so I assume this handler has role to play in context of parent application and its not required in your child applications. If that is case then you can simply remove it from child application's web.config. In order to do that you need to

1. Give name to your handler in parent application's web.config by adding name attribute to handler configuration.

   `<httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*" type="Intelligize.QC.Web.AuthorizationHandler, 
             Intelligize.QC.Web" validate="true" name="MyHandler" />
   </httpHandlers>`
2. Remove this handler from child's web.config

   `<httpHandlers>
      <remove name="MyHandler" />
   </httpHandlers>`

Comment: I want that handler to work on my child applications as well. As i said that handler will be the gateway (it means before running or opening any child application, handler from parent should call first) for parent as well as child apps

Comment: So i don't want to remove that httpHandlers from child apps web.config

Comment: In that case copy Intelligize.QC.Web dll in bin folder of child application.

Comment: Yeah i know that way but is there any other way around. Because i have more than 20 child applications